# XML must contain top level element

Tags: xml, post, soap, vbscript

I have this VBScript but it won't run since it keeps coming up with the error "XML must have top level element." Where is this error? I'm not very familiar with VBScript so if you could help in layman's terms it would be helpful.

```vb
    DIM oXMLHTTP
    DIM oXMLDoc
    function ProcessSend()  
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0") 
    Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") 
    oXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = getRef("HandleStateChange")  
    'strEnvelope = "username=user&password=pass" 
    strEnvelope="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"&_
    "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""                s:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"">"&_
     "<s:Body>"&_
     "<u:X_SendKey xmlns:u=""urn:panasonic-com:service:p00NetworkControl:1"">"&_
     "<X_KeyEvent>NRC_MUTE-ONOFF</X_KeyEvent>"&_
     "</u:X_SendKey>"&_
     "</s:Body>"&_
     "</s:Envelope>"
    'call msgbox(strEnvelope)
     call oXMLHTTP.open("POST","http://192.168.2.93:55000",false) 
     call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("User-Agent:","Panasonic iOS VR-CP UPnP/2.0") 
     call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Host:","192.168.2.93:55000") 
     call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type:","text/xml; charset=""utf-8""") 
     call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("SOAPACTION:","""urn:panasonic-    com:service:p00NetworkControl:1#X_SendKey""") 
     call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Length:","331") 
     call oXMLHTTP.send(strEnvelope) 
     end function 

     Sub HandleStateChange  
     if(oXMLHTTP.readyState = 4) then 
     dim szResponse: szResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText 
     call oXMLDoc.loadXML(szResponse) 
     if(oXMLDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0) then 
     'call msgbox("ERROR") 
     response = oXMLHTTP.responseText&" "&oXMLDoc.parseError.reason 
     call msgbox(oXMLDoc.parseError.reason) 
     else 
     Set prodList = oXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:listAllProductInformationResponse")(0).childNodes
    for each prod in prodList
    productText = productText &" "& prod.getAttribute("eanCode") & ";"&prod.getAttribute("productCode")&";"&prod.getAttribute("availability") &"#"& vbcrlf
    next
   'productText = productText & " "
    set fx=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    set x=fx.CreateTextFile("C:\pioneerLIST.txt",true) 
    x.WriteLine productText
    x.Close
    set x=nothing
    set fx=nothing        
    end if 
    end if 
    End Sub 

    processSend()
    </script>
    </job>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your XML ? from your code it contains only XML XSD deceleration w/o a **root** element (make sure to have in your XML primary root element which all the elements are decedents of it)